# How get active directory domain name in java

Tags: java

Tell me please
How can i get active directory domain name from java
I tried this
    System.out.println(System.getenv("USERDOMAIN"));
but I only get the name of the computer

======================

I did so
`InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            InetAddress[] ips = InetAddress.getAllByName(inet.getCanonicalHostName());
            usernameId.setText(System.getProperty("user.name"));
            if (ips != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ips.length; i++) {
                    String[] str = ips[i].toString().split("/");
                    if (!(str[1].startsWith("169") || str[1].contains(":")))
                        System.out.println("Computer name: " + str[0] + "\nIp address: " + str[1]);
                    computernameId.setText(str[0]);`

And i get ip address and computername.domainname

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
System.out.println(System.getenv("USERDNSDOMAIN"));
```

If that does not work, you can (as James Tanner said) try parsing through your system variables to find the one you want:

```
    Map<String, String> envMap = System.getenv();

    Iterator iter = envMap.entrySet().iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> pair = (Map.Entry<String, String>)iter.next();
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: I didn't think of just using Java to list your env vars in a platform-independent way. Clever.

Answer (score 1):

From [this article](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/WindowsServer2012/AdminTips/ActiveDirectory/environment-variables-and-preferences.html), try checking the `DomainName` environment variable.

Or, from [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/78089/find-name-of-active-directory-domain-controller), try the `LOGONSERVER`variable.

If that doesn't work, I'd recommend taking a look at your environment variables directly (directions vary depending on which version of Windows you're running) to find the one that actually contains the information you're looking for, then use that one.